# dynamic filtering with input_select() using ggvis in R

Tags: r, dynamic, filtering, dplyr, ggvis

I'm using the built in "cocaine" database that comes with the `ggvis` package in R to visualize the potency counts of cocaine in each state. The R package `dplyr` was also used.

Here's the first six lines of the `cocaine` dataset:

```
 state potency weight month price
1    WA      77    217     1  5000
2    CT      51    248     1  4800
3    FL      68     43     1  3500
4    OH      69    123     1  3500
5    MS      75    118     1  3400
6    VA      73    127     1  3000
```

The goal was to use `input_select()`within the ggvis package to create a drop down menu where one could select various states and see a histogram of the potency counts for that state. We managed to do that with this code:

```
state <- as.vector(unique(cocaine$state))

cocaine %>%
          ggvis(~potency) %>%
            filter(state == eval(input_select(
            choices = state,
            selected = "NY",
            label = "State"))) %>%
          layer_histograms(binwidth = 2)
```

**The question is why exactly we need the expression `input_select()` to be "evaluated" by `eval()`.** A guess may be that because`filter` is a function from the `dplyr` package and thus is not communicating in the environment with `ggvis`; `eval` therefore initializes it within the `ggvis` environment. Perhaps someone can chime in with a concept that may help us visualize this?

Comment: It's basically because of both ggvis and dplyr evaluate things in a special way (at a special time), so you need some way to tell who to do what first.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks Hadley!