# Set ggvis scale dynamically after filtering with input_select()

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, ggvis

This is a followup to [dynamic filtering with input_select() using ggvis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891020/dynamic-filtering-with-input-select-using-ggvis-in-r) .

What's wrong with this attempt to **dynamically set the domain of the `y` scale** based on the filtered data?

```
CYLINDER_CHOICES <- unique(mtcars$cyl)

mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  filter(cyl == eval(input_select(choices = CYLINDER_CHOICES))) %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain = c(0, 10 * scales:::precision(~mpg)))

Error in min(x, na.rm = na.rm) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Neither `~mpg`, nor `.(mpg)`, nor `.$mpg` works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to load dplyr first:

```
    library(dplyr)
```