# Interactive filtering and data visualisation

Tags: r, ggvis

In case of mtcars dataset how to populate the point/marks based on selection of cyl interactively.my code is not working

```
mtcars%>%ggvis(~mpg,~disp)%>%filter(cyl %in% input_select(c("4","6","8"),selected="4",map=as.numeric))%>%layer_points()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure *dplyr* is loaded and you currently need to use `eval` around `input_select` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891020/dynamic-filtering-with-input-select-using-ggvis-in-r).

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~mpg, ~disp) %>% 
    filter(cyl %in% eval(input_select(c("4", "6", "8"), selected = "4"))) %>% 
    layer_points()
```